# Refresh data source and connectionstring

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g

Currently I using EF 5 and Oracle ManagedDataAccess for my application. I create a small tool to enable user to configure database connection while the application is running.They communicate using WCF SOAP. So mainly the changes will be on the application.

However, I am not able to refresh data source once EF is able to connect. Connection String is able to refresh, but not data source.

```
public Entities(): base("name=MyEntities")
{
}

public UnitOfWork()
{
    _context = new Entities();
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    var connection = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["Entities"].ConnectionString;
    var connString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connection);
    context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connString.ProviderConnectionString;
}
```

My App.config will be look like

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Mapping.Models.csdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.ssdl|res://*/Mapping.Models.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=datasource1;password=123;persist security info=True;user id=user123&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <dataSource alias="datasource1" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=W2K8R2o11G020)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PCMS))) " />
      </dataSources>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
</configuration>
```

Once _context is established and able to connect to database, the datasource cannot be changed via my small tool. I still manage to change username and password with my small tool, but not data source (hostname, port, service name).
I tried to use OracleConnection.ClearAllPools(), but it is not working as well. Try to force new connection every time, not working too.

Is there any other way to make it happen?

Comment: have you tried passing the connection string into constructor?

Comment: Don't you create a new context with the new connectionstring?

Comment: Have you tried to .Reload()?  Here, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx, then follow the link that describes the 'reload' method.

Comment: @Mat yes, I did for connection string, but not datasouece.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, will do later if solution provided by Paul not working.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck not able. when I change dataSource Alias to other, it will hit error. "The underlying provider failed on Open.: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"